# Java Spring as a client for Akka based REST HTTP call

Tags: java, scala, http, spring-boot, akka

i have to call this REST service written in *scala-akka* project from *java-spring*.

my scala REST service is like

```
val route =
    post {
        path("notification" / "signUp"){
            headerValueByName("App_Key") { app_key => {
              handleWith {
                requestParameters: RequestParameters =>
                  //application specific implementation

              }
            }
            }
        }
```

which contains **App_Key and Content-Type in header** and **request parameters** in json format.

request parameters are like:

```
case class RequestParameters (
     var name: String,
     var email: String,
     var password: String,
     var hashKey: String
   )
```

so i have to call this **REST** service from **java spring**. I an struggling while calling `http://ipadress:port/notification/signUp` from java .

Comment: Any console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can call this via. Following Implementation :

```
try {

            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client.resource(http://ipadress:port/notification/signUp);

            JSONObject formData=new JSONObject();
            formData.put("name", UserName);
            formData.put("email", EmailId);
            formData.put("password", Password);
            formData.put("urlHash",HashKey);

            ClientResponse response = webResource.header("App_Key",xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks..it Worked for call asynchronously REST to Spray from Spring